# How to get selected index from nested array ? Angular - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to get selected item but in nested array.
First check my code:

```
  <div class="column-holder" *ngFor="let training of data.trainingExercise
            {
               "exerasdasd":""
                  },
                  {
                     "isWsadad":""
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now i need on click to get only selected set. Single Value!

```
   dsadsa(e){
     dsa.log(e)
     dsa.dsadas = e;
   }
```

This is good but i need only single value.
In my selectedSetValue i want to show only single value.
Right now i got values in all array.
I want only selected value and selected index. This is important selected values by index

Comment: (click)="selectedSet(set[i])"

Comment: No work. undefined.

Answer (score 0):

both here

```
  <div class="column-holder" *ngFor="let training of data.trainingExercises; let i = index;">
```

and here

```
  <div class="second-box-70" *ngFor="let set of training.sets; let i = index;">
```

you have `let i = index;`. Change the second one to `let j = index;` or something, so they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

please try this, change

```
  <div class="second-box-70" *ngFor="let set of training.sets; let i = index;">
    <div class="circle-exercise">

      <div class="circle-div">
        <div class="num-series">
         Series
        </div>
        <div class="circle" (click)="selectedSet(set)">
          <input [(ngModel)]="set.value" class="input-invisible-for-sets" type="type">
        </div>
      </div> 

    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="notes" *ngIf="selectedSetValue">
   {{ this.selectedSetValue.note }}
 </p>

</div>
```

to this

```
  <div class="second-box-70" *ngFor="let set of training.sets; let j = index;">
    <div class="circle-exercise">

      <div class="circle-div">
        <div class="num-series">
         Series
        </div>
        <div class="circle" (click)="selectedSet(set,j)">
          <input [(ngModel)]="set.value" class="input-invisible-for-sets" type="type">
        </div>
      </div> 

    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="notes" *ngIf="selectedSetValue">
   {{ this.selectedSetValue.note }}
 </p>

</div>
```

ts

```
    selectedSet(object,index){
        this.selectedSetValue = object;
    }
```